# How to get list of restaurants by using google maps. I want to get more than 20. Is it possible?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to get list of restaurants by using google maps. I want to get more than 20. Is it possible?
Btw, google places impossible to use, because in my case Ukrain Donetsk city doesn't show any restaurants in google places. But when I use simple google maps it shows all restaurants.
How to get this list of restaurants which google maps shows.
I.e. like this information:
Restaurant name and address.

Thank you very much.

Regards, Sergey.

Comment: Can you post the query that you're issuing using the Google Places API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use more than 20 results, and it's highly probable that we don't have proper categorised data for your area.

Try using the `keyword` parameter, you may have more luck. Something like this: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=37.422262,-122.169261&radius=500&keyword=restaurant&sensor=false&key=...`