# How to get a list of areas of the city Google Map Api?

Tags: json, api, dictionary, city

For example, when prompted:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=47.2333330,39.7000000&sensor=false
```

I get 'sublocality', but one. How do I get a full list of areas (sublocality) of any city its name?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete

Comment: This is an interesting method, but I want that list of all the areas of the city.

Comment: then search on google...this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558914/how-to-get-list-of-restaurants-by-using-google-maps-i-want-to-get-more-than-20